# How to load all the records from the server in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid which gets its data from the server. I don't need paging on this grid, i want
all the records loaded at once. I have tried using `loadonce` attribute, but it doesn't work.
How can i achieve this?

This is my grid

```
jQuery("#rowed4").jqGrid({
    url:'server.php?q=2',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'], 
    colModel: [
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55}, 
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, editable:true}, 
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100,editable:true}, 
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",editable:true}, 
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",editable:true}, 
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",editable:true}, 
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false,editable:true}
    ], 
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    pager: '#prowed4',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true, 
    sortorder: "desc",
    editurl: "server.php",
    caption: "Full control"
});
```

Comment: The usage of `loadonce: true` is the correct way. What you mean if you wrote "it doesn't work"? What is not work? Which format has the data which will be returned from `'server.php?q=2'`? How many items you returns? Do you sort the data by `id` on the server?

Comment: @Oleg I data is returned in `json` format. It is sorted, `loadonce` is not doing the job. But loads a maximum of 20 records.

Comment: The data `{ "total": 10, "page": 1, "records": 100, "rows":[ {"id" :"1","cell":["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]}]}` are in JSON format. Another data `[ {"id":"1","invdate":"cell11", "name":"cell12", "amount":"cell13"]}]` are also in JSON format. Both can be used but both need different `jsonReader`. Are data correctly loaded in both cases (with and without `loadonce: true`)? Then `jsonReader` will be not your problem. Do you defined the pager div with `id='prowed4'`? Can you see the pager on the grid and go to the next grid in case of `loadonce: true`?

Comment: @Oleg Yes, the data is displaying correctly. The pager is also working correctly.

Comment: What is your exact problem? You use `rowNum: 10`. So 10 rows per page will be displayed. You wrote that maximal 20 records will be loaded. So the pager do work in case of `loadonce: true` and you can go to the second page? How many records return the server (the URL 'server.php?q=2')

Comment: @Oleg About 70 rows. I later removed the `rowNum:10`, that's when the records defaulted to 20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use `loadonce: true` the server should return the *first page of data only*. In your case you use `rowNum: 10`. So the server should return maximal 10 records. So the server should return the subset of result based on `page` and `rows` parameter sent by jqGrid to the server

If you use `loadonce: true` the server should return *all records*. The server should *ignore* `page` and `rows` parameter sent by jqGrid. jqGrid will save all the data in the internal parameters `data` and `_index` and will implement for you paging, sorting and filtering/searching locally (without any additional requests to the server).

The rest should work automatically.